# Make Zurb Foundation Dropdown Go Upwards

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

Zurb Foundation's dropdown does not support going up (yes, I know it's called a dropdown):
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3011

I would love to make it do what Bootstrap offers in terms of "dropups":
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-dropup

Does anyone have any suggestions on accomplishing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This actually doesn't look too gnarly to implement, using the bootstrap dropup you can see what they did to get there.  If you use https://github.com/jlong/sass-bootstrap as a reference point you can see exactly the way they wrote the css for the dropup.  You will have to add to the mixin in the dropdown.scss for foundation, and also make changes to the foundation.dropdown.js to look for drop up. Line 127 where it is positioning the dropdown content will be of particular interest to you.